# using firebase for chatroom but broken every time when I run the project

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm new for android studio and coding a project  about using firebase for a chatroom.Then I met a problem :
every time I run the project,it's flashback and saying It's not responding,can
someone please help me for my problem!!appreciate!

**These are problems what  I met:**

```
    Process: com.example.chatroomdemo3, PID: 6010
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.chatroomdemo3/com.example.chatroomdemo3.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14 in com.example.chatroomdemo3:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #14 in com.example.chatroomdemo3:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14 in com.example.chatroomdemo3:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #14 in com.example.chatroomdemo3:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14 in com.example.chatroomdemo3:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:454)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:813)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1004)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1121)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:532)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:710)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:195)
        at com.example.chatroomdemo3.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7994)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7978)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
2022-09-20 17:50:29.871 6010-6010/com.example.chatroomdemo3 E/AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~ZjEoxav74b-XtewDIq5jeQ==/com.example.chatroomdemo3-pbmB3qrSrSLhR8HFlxAleA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~ZjEoxav74b-XtewDIq5jeQ==/com.example.chatroomdemo3-pbmB3qrSrSLhR8HFlxAleA==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system_ext/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:207)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
            ... 28 more
2022-09-20 17:50:29.900 6010-6010/com.example.chatroomdemo3 I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 6010 SIG: 9
```

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted more than **300** (three hundred) lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.  Please take a moment and read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I appreciate for telling me this important things,  I'll edit it for better way for my question!

Comment: So that error is more related to a FloatingActionButton, rather than Firebase, right?

Comment: Yes , this question is related to Floatingactionbutton bot firebase,but still appreciate!!  I'll remove the firebase tag.